# Get administrative_area_level_1 ISO code using Google places api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, iso, google-geocoding-api

I am working on app where I need to pass user state using format

```
country_iso_code-state_iso_code
```

I am using google places api autocomplete to search for cities in our [apps](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=[your_api_key]&types=(cities)&input=mexico) (android, iOS and web):
Then taking placeid to get place detail using:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=[your_api_key]&placeid=ChIJJfXQAJr114URJwWCbKB4-yc
```

Response for details query contains administrative_area_level_1 which is "administrative_area_level_1 indicates a first-order civil entity below the country level. Within the United States, these administrative levels are states. Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels."

[List](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes.htm) iso codes for each "state" in the selected country.

I looking for advice on how to map administrative_area_level_1 to its respective ISO code. Any help would be appreciated.

The solution I can think of is to use long name from details query response and map it against a dictionary created from list of iso codes on our server.

Comment: after reading the documentation again.. seems like the way out is to make your own dictionary...

Comment: kaho - We did end up going the route of making our custom dictionary and putting that behind a microservice.

Comment: We ended up creating our own microserivce with map generated using ISO codes and place place. So now the app makes a secondary request to our microservice to get this data.